# creating aggregate expressions in MongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I have been using `MongoDB Compass` to create `Aggregate Expressions` for my MongoDB database. But it does not support all pipeline aggregations.

I was wondering if there is a better way to do that?

Comment: what do you mean by it doesn't support all pipelines ? You can use **robo3T** to access DB - Where you'll have shell kind of feel & most people prefer it. Additionally you can use https://mongoplayground.net to test your queries with sample data

Comment: _"But it does not support all pipeline aggregations."_ Please tell what aggregation stages or operators you are referring to. Is there any specific operation you are trying to perform?

Comment: `$merge`, `$replaceWith` etc.

Comment: MongoDB aggregation framework supports `$merge` and `$replaceWith` in the server version 4.2. I see the options to use `$merge` and `replaceRoot` with Compass 1.19.6  Note that `$replaceWith` is an alias for `$replaceRoot` stage.